# Logistic regression vs segmentized logistic regression

Tags: regression, modeling, regression-coefficients

This might be a very rookie question. I need help interpreting the results of my logistic regression.

Assume I have the following model: `y ~ categorical + numerical`.

If I run this model, I will get the following coefficient for my numerical variable: $w_{num_{full}}$.

Now, my categorical variable has 2 levels: A, and B. If I filter the data for each level and build `y ~ numerical`, I will get $w_{num_{A}}$, $w_{num_{B}}$.

Now I am trying to make sense of how $w_{num_{full}}$ are related $w_{num_{A}}$, $w_{num_{B}}$, especially in my case that they are very further apart. Is my full model even valid when the segments show so much difference? What happens if the coefficient for one of the segments is not even statistically significant?

Is it suggested to do segmented logistic regression, or there is a way of interpreting the results of the full model?

Comment: The relation among three slopes ($w$s) are data dependent. There is fix relation. Generally $w_f$ is between $w_A$ and $w_B$, but it is possible that  $w_f >$ or $<$ both $w_A$ and $w_B$

Comment: So my full model might be misleading as the slope for categories might cancel each other out in the full data. Is it suggested to do segmented logistic regression, or there is a way of interpreting the results of the full model?

Comment: Fit a model with interaction ``log(p/(1-p)) =  constant + categorical + numerical + categorical*numerical ``, then check if the interaction between ``categorical`` and `` numerical ``. If significant, A and B have different slopes. If not significant, keep your full model, and your $w_f$ is the common slope for A and B.